# Change link without change the name

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to change link without changing the name?
ex:

```
linllabeltext.link = "http://mylink.com/";
```

doesn't work

and this change the name

```
linklabeltext.test = "http://mylink.com/"
```

change the test

I have added this function at click

```
Process.Start(linklabetext.text);
```

how?

```
full code:

private void (......)
{
.....
var name = result.name;
.......
labelLink1.text = name;
}

private void labelLink1_click....
{
Process.Start(labelLink1.text);
}
```

but this code change the name of labelLink1 in a link es: http://mysate.com but the name of labelLink is Visit a Web Site

Comment: What is `linklabeltext`? Also, I have no idea what are you talking about.

Comment: visual studio 2010 in c# create a LinkLabel!

Comment: `linklabeltext.test`?  Are you sure about that?  Can you copy/paste your actual code to avoid typos?  If there's a typo in your question about the code, there could very well be one in your code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linklabel.aspx).  Specifically where they create the `LinkLabel` and set it's link(s) and text:

```
this.linkLabel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel();
this.linkLabel1.Text = "Register Online.  Visit Microsoft.  Visit MSN.";
if(this.linkLabel1.Text.Length >= 45)
{
    this.linkLabel1.Links[0].LinkData = "Register";
    this.linkLabel1.Links.Add(24, 9, "www.microsoft.com");
    this.linkLabel1.Links.Add(42, 3, "www.msn.com");
    //  The second link is disabled and will appear as red.
    this.linkLabel1.Links[1].Enabled = false;
}
```

I've never actually used this control before, but it appears that you set the `.Text` to any string and then set the "links" to correspond to substrings within the `.Text` property.

**Edit**: I just noticed that you're also using the wrong event for clicking on the link.  You don't want to bind to the `LinkLabel` control's `Click` event.  It has a `LinkClicked` event which puts more information in the event about the link being clicked.  Take a look at, of course, the [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked.aspx):

```
private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify that the link was visited.
    this.linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;

    // Navigate to a URL.
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.microsoft.com");
}
```

Comment: @jolly: Can you be more specific?  I'm pretty sure the MSDN examples are on the ball for how to use their own controls.  What isn't working and how isn't it working?  When you step through the code, at what point does it do something you didn't expect?  What was the state of the relevant objects/data when this happened?  You have to do some basic debugging here.

Comment: i have insert the code start debugger but the text does not change and the link does not open

Comment: @jolly: I'm afraid that isn't particularly helpful.  Can you edit the question to include your updated code?  Also, I've noticed something else wrong in your code and have updated my answer accordingly, please see above.  You appear to be using the wrong `Click` event.  That control has a custom event called `LinkClicked` which has the information you need to open the link (information that is _not_ in the `.Text` property).

Comment: lnkName.Text = "Hi " + name;
                lnkName.LinkClicked += (o, e) => System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");

Comment: @jolly: And is the event being fired when you click on it?  Are you adding an actual link to the `.Links` collection?  You may need to do that in order to fire the event.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno if it'll help or not, since I'm not completely sure what you're after, but [here's a quick example](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1906889/LinkLabelExample.zip) of how to use a LinkLabel. Enter any valid url in the text box, click the link below it, and the url will be opened by calling Process.Start(). The text of the LinkLabel will not change, regardless of what url you enter. (Which I *think* is what you're after.)

[image]

Comment: No problem. Hope that helped.